# PHP, cómo tratar campos vacios para obviarlos en la consulta

Tags: php, codeigniter, formularios

estoy usando Codeigniter como framework. Estoy haciendo una página web de búsqueda de excursiones, el caso es que quiero hacer un formulario en el que se pueda especificar el precio mínimo,descripción, precio máximo, fecha y ciudad de una excursión para hacer una búsqueda, de tal forma que, si yo solo relleno el precio, me muestre todas las excursiones en ese rango de precio obviando los campos que se dejen vacios.

Pero a la hora de hacer el modelo hago esto:

/* buscar_actividades */

```
function buscar_actividad($params){

    /* comprobar los campos que me envian */

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('excursiones');
    $this->db->where(array(
                            'ciudad' => $params['ciudad'],
                            'precio' => $params['precio'],
                            'fecha_inicio' => $params['fecha'],
                            'descripcion' => $params['descripcion']
                            )
    );

    // resultado de la consulta  
    $consulta = $this->db->get();
    $resultado = $consulta->row();

    return $resultado;

}
```

Y evidentemente, no me muestra ningún resultado porque busca campos cuyo campo descripción por ejemplo, están vacíos.

Se me ocurre un par de formas para arreglarlo pero creo que no son nada eficientes.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo semi-facil?

Comment: Con la funcióm empty($campo) verifica si está vacío o no

Answer (score 1):

Espero que esto te sirva:

```
public function buscar_actividad($params){
// Defines las key que son necesarias
$req_where_keys = array('ciudad', 'precio', 'fecha_inicio', 'descripcion');

// Creas un nuevo array
$where_array = array();

// Valida que existan las keys que necesitas y si no existen simplemente no las agrega
foreach ($req_where_keys as $where_key) {
    if (array_key_exists($where_key, $params)) {
      // Valida que no sea vacío
      if ($where_array[$where_key] != '') {
        $where_array[$where_key] = $params[$where_key];
      }
    }
}

// Realizas tu consulta
$this->db->select('*')->from('excursiones')->where($where_array);

// resultado de la consulta
$consulta = $this->db->get();
$resultado = $consulta->row();

return $resultado;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que haría es componer el array:

```
array(
          'ciudad' => $params['ciudad'],
          'precio' => $params['precio'],
           'fecha_inicio' => $params['fecha'],
           descripcion' => $params['descripcion']
 )
```

Según los datos en $params, por ejemplo:

```
$datos = [];

if ($params['ciudad'] !== ''){
    $datos['ciudad'] = $params['ciudad'];
}
```

y así con todos los campos, cuando termines solo tendrás aquellos que han sido ingresados por el usuario.

saludos

Answer (score 0):

Al final hice esto:

Hugo me dió una pista creando el array con los índices, gracias.

```
function buscar_actividad($params){

        $key = array ('ciudad','precio','fecha','descripcion');

        /* comprobar los campos que me envian */
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('excursiones');

        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            if ($value!=""){
                $this->db->where($key,$params[$key]);
            }
        }

        // resultado de la consulta  
        $consulta = $this->db->get();
        $resultado = $consulta->row();

        return $resultado;

    }
```